# how to turn a command line cURL request into php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a php script that will use this new site called Oanda and trade virtual money on the Forex market.

I am trying to convert this command line code in to php:

```
$curl -X POST -d "instrument=EUR_USD&units=1000&side=buy&type=market" https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/accounts/6531071/orders
```

If anyone can give source code or explain what the `-X POST` and the `-d` mean and how to convert them to php that would be awesome.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and if there is any ***authentication*** please include them..

***POST*** Means the **data** should be passed as post request

***-d*** Means The **data** you should pass in the request

```
//the data you should passed
$data = array(
    "instrument" => 'EUR_USD',
    "units" => "1000",
    "side" => "buy",
    "type" => "market",
);

//encode it as json to become a string
$data_string = json_encode($data);
// print_r($data_string);

$curl = curl_init('https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/accounts/6531071/orders');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

//the content type(please reffer your api documentation)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//set post data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);//close the curl request

if ($result) {
    print_r($result); // print the response
}
```

Plese reffer [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) for more information